# Change Input Focus and Margin/Padding for Checkbox Field

Tags: javascript, css, focus

I used CSS to change the original labels for a checkbox question and the input text field that appears after you check the box, but after adding the code, it removed some of the margin and padding, and the input text field no longer has the focus applied to it.

Here is the link to the form:  https://donorbox.org/youthminds. Just select any amount and click next to get to the second part of the form.

I included the original HTML code below, and before and after images at the bottom.

I used the CSS code below to change the checkbox field label and the input text label which appears after you click the box.

**CSS:**

```
label[for="is_donating_company"] span.mdl-checkbox__label { font-size: 0 !important; }
label[for="is_donating_company"] span.mdl-checkbox__label:after { content: "Add Organization Name"; font-size: 16px; }

label[for="donation_donating_company"] { font-size: 0 !important; }
label[for="donation_donating_company"]:before { content: "Organization Name"; font-size: 16px; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mdl-grid "><div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-ripple-effect--ignore-events is-upgraded is-checked" for="is_donating_company" data-upgraded=",MaterialCheckbox,MaterialRipple" style="height: 24px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="is_donating_company" id="is_donating_company" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
<span class="mdl-checkbox__label">This donation is on behalf of a company</span><span class="mdl-checkbox__focus-helper"></span>
<span class="mdl-checkbox__box-outline">
<span class="mdl-checkbox__tick-outline"></span></span>
<span class="mdl-checkbox__ripple-container mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-ripple--center" data-upgraded=",MaterialRipple">
<span class="mdl-ripple"></span></span></label></div></div>

<div id="donating_company_fields" style="">
<div class="mdl-grid"><div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialTextfield">
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" autocomplete="off" data-id="text" type="text" name="donation[donating_company]" id="donation_donating_company">
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="donation_donating_company">Donating Company</label></div></div></div></div>
```

I tried to see what went wrong, but I couldn't figure it out. It appears when either label is changed, some of the styling goes away or is altered. I would like to have it back to how it was before, with the margin/padding and the focus. I can only add CSS and Javascript, I can't edit the HTML.

**Images:**

*Original:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV1vO.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIIvh.png

*With CSS Code Changes:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAhvh.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kdpa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend some time inspecting the page, but couldn't figure it out quickly enough.
If you can use javascript, just replace the texts with jquery.
For example:
    $('label[for="donation_first_name"]').text('New Label');

Comment: I tried adding: $('label[for="is_donating_company"]').text('Add Organization Name');

But, it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: for that specific label the correct code is $('label[for="is_donating_company"] .mdl-checkbox__label').text('Add Organization Name');

Comment: I still wasn't able to get it to work, but I found code for an OnLoad function on a similar question, and added your code to that, and it worked. Using the same code, I was able to change the input text field label as well (and keep the focus applied). Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Full Code:

<script>
function addLoadEvent(func) {  
      var oldonload = window.onload;  
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {  
        window.onload = func;  
      } else {  
        window.onload = function() {  
          if (oldonload) {  
            oldonload();  
          }  
          func();  
        }  
      }  
    }  

   addLoadEvent(function() {  
$('label[for="is_donating_company"] .mdl-checkbox__label').text('Add Organization Name');

    });  
</script>

Answer (score 0):

**Checkbox Field Label:**

```
<script>
function addLoadEvent(func) {  
      var oldonload = window.onload;  
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {  
        window.onload = func;  
      } else {  
        window.onload = function() {  
          if (oldonload) {  
            oldonload();  
          }  
          func();  
        }  
      }  
    }  

   addLoadEvent(function() {  
$('label[for="is_donating_company"] .mdl-checkbox__label').text('Add Organization Name');

    });  
</script>
```

**Input Text Field Label:**

```
<script>function addLoadEvent(func) {  
      var oldonload = window.onload;  
      if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {  
        window.onload = func;  
      } else {  
        window.onload = function() {  
          if (oldonload) {  
            oldonload();  
          }  
          func();  
        }  
      }  
    }  

   addLoadEvent(function() {  
$('label[for="donation_donating_company"]').text('Organization Name');

    });  
</script>
```